# How to view list of downloaded programs on ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, downloads

Is there any way to see a list of downloaded programs like in the Windows 7 control panel?

The downloads section of My Files doesn't appear to hold anything even though I successfully downloaded youtube-dl (and would like to remove it) through the terminal.

Very new to Linux and compsci in general, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be "downloading" programs. If you are new, you should be using the Ubuntu Software application. Your list of downloaded software is in it's "installed" tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apt in the terminal to get a list of all installed (downloaded) files:

```
[sudo] apt list --installed
```

Comment: Thanks, that's where I found what I was looking for. Can you answer one more thing though? What's suppose to appear in the downloads folder?

Comment: `~/Downloads` folder contain downloaded file via browser.